# How to run two GUIs in Python in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, pyqt, pyqt4

We are talking about python 2.7 and PyQt4.

I'm working with an open-source program for the eeg analysis called PyCorder, that received data from a system electrodes-amplifier and plot them in a GUI; we can consider it as a black box for the purposes of this question. I implemented a simple interface with Qt designer. My aim is to run both the PyCorder and my interface at the same time in a way that they can exchange data between them.

Here the lines of the code where my interface is launched:

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

I guess it's common to any interface done with Qt designer;
Following, the PyCorder launching part:

---

```
def main(args):

    print "Starting PyCorder, please wait ...\n"
    setpriority(priority=4)
    app = Qt.QApplication(args)
    try:
        win = None
        win = MainWindow()
        win.showMaximized()
        if ShowConfirmationDialog:
            accept = Qt.QMessageBox.warning(None, "PyCorder Disclaimer", ConfirmationText, 
                                            "Accept", "Cancel", "", 1)
            if accept == 0:
                win.usageConfirmed = True
                app.exec_()
            else:
                win.close()
        else:
            win.usageConfirmed = True
            app.exec_()
    except Exception as e:
        tb = GetExceptionTraceBack()[0]
        Qt.QMessageBox.critical(None, "PyCorder", tb + " -> " + str(e))
        if win != None:
            win.close()

    # show the battery disconnection reminder
    if ShowBatteryReminder and win and win.usageConfirmed:
        DlgBatteryInfo().exec_()

    print "PyCorder terminated\n"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

Is it sufficient to know just these two parts of the respective codes to answer my question? Is there any toolbox that can be useful to reach my goal?

Comment: I like wx so im not sure on the terminology with QT ... but you can certainly display 2 `Frames` (Windows) at the same time

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why do you want to run 2 windows in parallel if they can coexist without problems? What problems do you have now? What advantages do you think you will have?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I try to answer clearly.

Comment: I want to run these two windows at the same time in a way that they can exchange data. The first one, PyCorder, is a complex program, developed by a company that works on the field of Eeg Analysis, and to obtain a deep understanding of it would require months at least for me (I'm a newbie), and unfortunately I don't have this time. Until now,my attempt has been to import in PyCorder's Main my app and to write a line to launch it inside the method 'def main' that I reported above. It didn't work, my best result was to launch my app after closing PyCorder

Comment: I want to take some data inside that PyCorder, takes from some electrodes, process and display them in real time, and since I cannot properly modify PyCorder code, i need to build a new GUI and run it in parallel to PyCorder.

What do you exatcly need with the sentence "they can coexist without problems"?

Answer (score 0):

The best idea comes to my mind is to use multi processing libraries in order to run QT several times. *[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)* is one of the libraries you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I prefer to use a central "window manager" to acts as the owner and inter-communication hub of the two windows. Below is a sample of that technique that will need to be adapted to your needs. Note that I use Qt5. I tested on Qt5, and then attempted to translate to Qt4 without testing. It should be right, but might need a little tweeking.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class WindowManager(QtCore.QObject):
    """ 
    Inheriting from QObject has benefits.
    For instance, the WindowManager can not have pyQtSignal members, if needed
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__()
        self.firstWindow = FirstWindow(self)
        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow(self)
        self.firstWindow.show()
        self.secondWindow.show()

class FirstWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, manager):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.manager = manager
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.clickyButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Click me")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.clickyButton)
        self.clickyButton.clicked.connect(self.clickyButtonClicked)
    def clickyButtonClicked(self, checked=None):
        self.manager.secondWindow.setMessage("Clicky button clicked")

class SecondWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, manager):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.manager = manager
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.messageBox = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.messageBox)
    def setMessage(self, message):
        self.messageBox.setText(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = WindowManager()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```